# Why is the filter variable not multiplied? Is this loop related?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have to create a function `power`. That took in a base an a exp argument. Depending on the num exp equals I have to multiply the base number by itself. This is my code below.

```
    function power(base, exp) {
      var nums = [];
      var filter = 1;

      for(var i = 0; i < exp; i++) {
        nums.push(base);
      }
        for(var j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
        var ele = nums[j];
        filter * ele;
        }
       return filter;
     }

    power(5,6)
```

Comment: `filter * ele;` => `filter = filter * ele;`

Comment: or `filter *= ele`

Comment: Why are you not using [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the value of `filter` in each step as below:

```
filter = filter * ele;
```

or more compact:

```
filter *= ele;
```

By the way you don't need to make use of the array `nums`. Check the following snippet, where I have added some validation logic in the start and then we have only one for statement.

```js
function power(base, exp) {
    if(isNaN(base) || isNaN(exp)) {
        throw "Both base and exp should be numbers.";
    }
    if(base===0 && exp!==0){
        return Infinity;
    }
    if(exp<0){ 
        return 1/power(base, -exp);
    }
    if(exp===0){
        return 1;
    }

    var power = 1;
    for(var i=0; i<exp; i++){
        power = power * base;
    }

    return power;
}
```

Comment: Or use: `filter *= ele`

Comment: Why re-implement [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)?

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree 100% with you, but OP tried to implement it. Hence I included this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your function:

```
function power(base, exp) {
    return Math.pow(base, exp);
}

power(5,6);
```

Or even simpler, just call `Math.pow`:

```
Math.pow(5, 6);
```

Comment: They wan't me to solve this problem without math.pow

Comment: "They"? Who are you talking about? Do you mean... hey, it's your homework?!